# Error: "The operation can’t be completed because one or more required items can’t be found. (Error code -43)"

Tags: macos, finder, hard-drive, error

I accidentally pulled an NTFS hard drive out of my Mac OS X Mavericks machine several times and realized that I accidentally created multiple entries of many different names in my `/Volumes/` folder. Now I have `storage_1`, `storage_2`, `storage_3`, `passport`, etc. in my `/Volumes/` folder.

I tried a few solutions to unmount the drives (they didn't show up as unmountable however since they technically don't exist as real drive volumes). I tried a few quick `rm filename -r` and `rmdir filename` commands to no avail.

The error I get when I try to delete ANYTHING in Finder, however, is

> The operation can’t be completed because one or more required items can’t be found.
>
> (Error code -43).

Obviously I Google'd the answer to this problem and was able to fix it initially by fixing my hard drive permissions. However, this fix didn't work for the `/Volumes/` folder, just every other folder. Now, nothing works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: My symptoms: 
- Error -43 when trying to delete the file it self. 
- Deleting the parent dir showed "file in use.." when emptying trash.
- The get info displayed "Unknown permissions".
- Ran Disk Utility and ran -> First Aid and found some errors regarded Zeroed out sectored.

Tried:
- PRAM/SMB reset also no effect.
- Delete commands in terminal also  in recovery mode - no effect. 

The solution:
- Backup to time machine & exclude that particular file's parent dir.
- Reboot in recovery, using disk utility, erase the problem drive completely,
- Restore from Time machine

Comment: I had a similar issue but when using Ventura. Turns out I had to disable System Integrity Protection which is available in recovery mode. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A simple shut down, then start, of OS X should automatically remove debris from

`/Volumes`

If you like: disconnect/eject any removable media before the start.

Or simply leave the media in place, and restart.

---

There may be other approaches to dealing with volume debris whilst the OS is running but in my experience, it's often better to restart.

### Also recommended

Error -43 may truly indicate a file system inconsistency, so use Recovery OS Disk Utility to verify affected file systems.

Comment: Unfortunately I had tried the shutdown, restart method to no avail. However, upon later inspection, I realized I was using the command `rm drive_name -r`, instead of `rm -r drive_name`. Problem solved. Such simple stupid mistakes on my part.

Comment: Relaunching Finder solved the issue for me.

Comment: also relaunching finder solved

Comment: simply ejecting and reconnecting the external hdd solved the issue

Answer (score 25):

You can search Force Quit & submit it. Then choose Finder and Relauch it. Finally move to trash item 's icon which you want remove

Comment: I'm not sure how this will help.

Comment: Why not? Did you not try it? (By "force quit and submit it", we just mean quit and restart the finder; at least on my system Command-Q works for the Finder, too. No need to "force quit" and after relaunching, things were normal. (Although I have occasionally encountered strange Finder issues that required a reboot for the situation to resolve.)

At least when I encountered this bizarre behavior (on my start-up drive, with documents in my Downloads directory, quitting and re-launching the Finder app did, indeed, resolve the situation.

Comment: This helped me fixing the issue without rebooting my system. But the answer could be improved to just right-click Finder and hit "relaunch".

Comment: Thanks for this! This fixed an issue on macOS Sierra where one of the user accounts couldn't delete files. I opened Activity Monitor, selected Finder in the list, and chose "Force Quit". When I clicked Finder again in the Dock to start it anew, I could delete files.

Answer (score 3):

I had previously gotten the  Error 43 on my Mac.  So Here's the fix: [Error Code 43 Mac](http://relisticle.com/fix-error-code-43-mac-finder-error/).

To fix, what you need to do is basically two steps

1. Reset the PRAM.  From a powered off state, hold <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>  <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>  <kbd>P</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> until you hear the startup chimes 3 times, then release and allow your system to boot normally.
2. (Optional)  Delete the locked files.  In Terminal, execute the following command:  `chflags -R nouchg`.  Then open your Trash, select all the item (<kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>), drag everything to the Terminal window, then press <kbd>Return ⏎</kbd>.  Empty your Trash

If you follow these steps, it should solve the problem.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The 1) option did it form me. Restart your mac, while holding the specified buttons